# How to append value in data cell using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
rows: const <DataRow>[
  DataRow(
    cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text("here")),
      DataCell(Text('19')),
      DataCell(Text('Student')),
      DataCell(Text('19')),
      DataCell(Text('Student')),
    ],
  ),
],
```

My data:

```
items = {'code':itemcode,'name':itemname,'rate':itemrate};
```

How to append the data into data cell?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question correctly but here goes:

You `items` object still looks like json, so go from json to a class:

```
StudentRating.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return StudentRating(
      code: json['itemcode'],
      name: json['itemname'],
      rate: json['itemrate'],
    );
}
```

Then inside the DataTable, you can loop thru the list of `StudentRating's`:

```
DataTable(
    columns: [],
    rows: studentRatingsList.map((rating) => 
        DataRow(
            cells: [
                DataCell(Text(rating.code))
                DataCell(Text(rating.name))
                DataCell(Text(rating.rate))
            ]
        ),
    ),
),
```